# What is the test of significance for kernel canonical correlations?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, kernel-trick, canonical-correlation

I am trying to conduct a test of independence between two multivariate datasets. For canonical correlation, I have used Wilk’s lambda test. What should be the test statistics for kernel CCA. I believe I can use F-statistics, need a measurement of degrees of freedom for the same