# Are there random matrix results like Marcenko-Pastur, but for CCA?

Tags: canonical-correlation, random-matrix

The Marcenko-Pastur law is about asymptotic distributions of eigenvalues. It starts from a simple null model (iid zero-mean Gaussian entries) and derives a distribution for the spectrum. In PCA, this allows a data analyst to select the number of principal components using a p-value cutoff.

Is there a similar law that governs the distribution of correlations in CCA? I want to select the dimension of the latent space(s) using the same strategy as above.

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259490/what-is-the-test-of-significance-for-kernel-canonical-correlations) is very similar to mine, but it's not answered and it's a little less general. (Asking for a test about any relationship at all is like asking "Is the latent space is zero dimensional" whereas I want to select the dimension). It's also about kernel CCA, and I am content with just plain CCA.

Comment: +1. I don't know a theoretical answer, but in practice it is usually easy to obtain this distribution via simulation. Generate two matrices of the same size as your X and Y with iid Gaussian entries and compute CCA. One can repeat this several times to get a sense of variability. One can also simply shuffle the rows of Y, to avoid using the Gaussianity assumption. (Shuffling rows of Y destroys all correlations between X and Y, while keeping the covariance of Y unchanged.)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps check this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.7194.pdf, which contains some random matrix results on the CCA matrix mentioned in your post.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/336517)